# Iframe trying to call getUserMedia from a document with a different security origin than its top-level frame

Tags: javascript, macos, iframe, safari, mobile-safari

IFrame keep giving "Trying to call getUserMedia from a document with a different security origin than its top-level frame."

1. `https://www.client.com` has iframe service in there site
2. `<iframe allow="geolocation; microphone; camera; midi; encrypted-media;" src="https://supplier.supplier.com/services"></iframe>`
3. Now on Google chrome with those flag `allow="geolocation; microphone; camera; midi; encrypted-media;`, it works, but on Safari not working

How to make it work on Safari, so that different origin can use the service? where `client.com` buy service from `supplier.com` both using HTTPS.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found any solutions to it?

Comment: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=182638 - can you retest what Safari advised? and report here or there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=182638#c8

> 2018-03-10 21:38:59 PST: Behaving correctly in latest STP.

Please TEST and report here or there.